# Performance of java comparator?

Tags: java, sorting

Is the Comparator interface fast enough as compared to a normal sort? What algorithm does compareTo use when comparing two different objects?

Comment: *fast enough* - for what purpose, in what circumstances? There is no way to know, fast enough for one purpose, in one context, could be completely unsuitable in another.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the Comparator interface fast enough as compared to a normal sort?

This heavily depends on the sort algorithm more than the comparison logic (usually).

> What algorithm does compareTo use when comparing two different objects?

It depends on the implementation of `compareTo` method in the class.

Should you worry about the performance of the application? Only if proven that it is a bottleneck by usage of a profiler.